# find out unprotected commonly used subdirectories

Tags: brute-force

I try to solve a pentesting challenge where I have to find out a directory, which is unprotected from directory listing.

I tried to find it with

```
wfuzz -c -z file,'wordlist.txt' --hc 404 http://challenge01.root-me.org/realiste/ch3/FUZZ
```

But my wordlist is not suiting the task. Usually you are searching for words like

```
admin
images
develop
dev
disabled
secret
backup
bak
includes
functions
bin
lib
...
```

Or is there a better tool for this task?

How do I use brute force to find out all possible directories that could exist?

Comment: Why do you have to use wfuzz? Why not use a directory brute-forcing tool and a directory brute force dictionary? Do you want to know how to create the dictionary or do you want a dictionary that would work? How did you create or acquire the `wordlist.txt` you used above?

Comment: I clarified my question

Comment: so, from my comment, have you looked up directory brute forcing tools? ... there are a few ...

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for, sometimes it is not easy to find out the right search words

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous tools called "directory brute forcing tools" for example [DirBuster](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-like-pro-find-directories-websites-using-dirbuster-0157593/):

> #### Directory Traversal Attacks
>
> Directory traversal is a type of attack where we can navigate out of the default or index directory that we land in by default. By navigating to other directories, we may find directories that contain information and files that are thought to be unavailable